# Common tangent of two ellipses

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Find the common tangent to: $4(x-4)^2 +25y^2 = 100$ and $4(x+1)^2 +y^2 = 4$.

I have found the derivatives of the above two equations:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{16-4x}{25y}$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{-(4x+4)}{y}$

What do I do next?

Comment: Condition such that $y=mx+c$ is tangent to an ellipse in standard form is $y=mx\pm\sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}$. So find tangent for one ellipse and solve the other tangent with that ellipse and equate discriminant=0.

Comment: http://www.askiitians.com/forums/Analytical-Geometry/24/5789/common-tangents.htm

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270055/common-tangent-to-a-circle-and-ellipse

Comment: Put the equations into standard from (showing centers and semi-axes) and sketch the graphs. The answers then are obvious. There is no need to calculate the derivatives to find the answer, but they are useful to validate the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

1)$\dfrac{(x-4)^2}{5^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{2^2}=1;$

2) $(x+1)^2 +\dfrac{y^2}{2^2} =1;$

Draw them.

1) Major axis $5$, minor axis $2.$
Centred at $(4,0).$

2) Major axis $2$, minor axis $1.$
Centred at $(-1,0).$

The only common tangents :

1) At $(4,2)$ for ellipse $1.$

2) At $(-1,2)$ for ellipse $2.$

$y=2$;

Check your $dy/dx$ at these points.

Can you find the other common tangent?